# Warning: format '%f' expectts a matching 'double' argument (pt-br)(en)

Tags: c, sintaxe, float, double

Meu primeiro post aqui e gostaria de saber, porque quando vou compilar meu código ele dá um erro dizendo que o formato `%f` espera um `double`, sendo que o `f` é usado para `float` e a variável que eu estou colocando é `float`.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float proceNotas(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3, char letter);

int main(){
    float n1, n2, n3;
    char letra;
    printf("Digite a primeira nota: ");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("Digite a segunda nota: ");
    scanf("%f", &n2);
    printf("Digite a terceira nota: ");
    scanf("%f", &n3);
    getchar();
    printf("Digite a operacao desejada: A) media aritmetica\nP) Media ponderada\nH) Media harmonica\n");
    letra = getchar();
    printf("\nA media do aluno é: %f"), proceNotas(n1, n2, n3, letra);
    return 0;
}

float proceNotas(float nota1, float nota2, float nota3, char letter){
    float arit, pond, harm;

    switch(letter){
        case 'A':
        arit = nota1+nota2+nota3/3;
        return arit;
        break;
        case 'P':
        pond = (nota1*5)+(nota2*3)+(nota3*2)/5+3+2;
        return pond;
        break;
        case 'H':
        harm = 3/(1/nota1)+(1/nota2)+(1/nota3);
        return harm;
        break;
        default:
        return printf("Operacao invalida!");
    }
}
```

[image: Segue o print com o erro no console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vários erros.

Aqui:

```
printf("\nA media do aluno é: %f"), proceNotas(n1, n2, n3, letra);
```

deveria ser:

```
printf("\nA media do aluno é: %f", proceNotas(n1, n2, n3, letra));
```

Seus cálculos estão errados. Estude a precedência dos operadores.

Aqui:

```
arit = nota1+nota2+nota3/3;
```

creio que não quer dividir apenas a nota3 por 3 mas sim toda a soma:

```
arit = (nota1+nota2+nota3)/3;
```

Aqui:

```
pond = (nota1*5)+(nota2*3)+(nota3*2)/5+3+2;
```

deve ser:

```
pond = ((nota1*5)+(nota2*3)+(nota3*2)) / (5+3+2);
```

e aqui:

```
harm = 3/(1/nota1)+(1/nota2)+(1/nota3);
```

deve ser:

```
harm = 3 / ((1/nota1)+(1/nota2)+(1/nota3));
```

Comment: Me sinto até envergonhado, muito obrigado, olhando assim, sao varios erros bobos

Comment: @AxelFelix, aceite a resposta do anonimo :). Ele respondeu mas você não marcou a resposta dele como útil e nem aceitou a resposta

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário

Answer (score 0):

A função `printf()` é uma *função com número de argumentos variável* (com `...` no protótipo). Assim sendo, os argumentos que caem sob o domínio dos `...` sofrem as [promoções predefinidas para argumentos (link em inglês)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7)

> ... The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Estas promoções predefinidas incluem a conversão de valores tipo `float` para valores tipo `double`.

Ou seja, não é possível enviar um valor de tipo `float` para dentro do `printf()`. Não faz sentido haver uma conversão para esse tipo, por isso a conversão `"%f"` é para tipo `double`.

```
    float xf; double xd; long double xl;
    xf = xd = xl = 3.14159265L;
    printf("%f %lf\n", xf, xf);       // %f ou %lf para float/double
    printf("%f %lf\n", xd, xd);
    printf("%Lf\n", xl);              // %Lf para long double
```

https://ideone.com/nr6nqy